# Is it possible to open a WPF IneractionRequest (Prism) without the xaml?

Tags: wpf, prism

In xaml you normally have to have a InteractionRequestTrigger in InteractionTriggers, but I was curious if there was a way to do all this in code behind.  I've gotten some code up and running, but I think what's wrong is the Raised event in my InteractionRequest isn't getting set.

I'm sure many of you want to ask "why are you doing this?" but ignore that for now please.

```
    private void OnInteractionRequestEvent(InteractionRequestEventInfo info)
    {
        lock (_irLock)
        {
            var ir = new InteractionRequest<INotification>();
            InteractionRequestTrigger irt = new InteractionRequestTrigger();
            PopupNotificationAction pna = new PopupNotificationAction();
            pna.ElementToParent = info.Parent;
            pna.CenterOverAssociatedObject = true;
            pna.IsModal = true;
            pna.WindowContent = info.View;
            irt.Actions.Add(pna);

            irt.SourceObject = ir;
            ir.Raise(info.Notification, info.Callback);
        }
    }
```

This is what I have so far.
PopupNotificationAction is something we wrote that works when used in the normal way with xaml. It dervies from PopupWindowAction

Comment: So, what made you think this was a good idea? *(That is not the same as "why are you doing this"!)* Are you getting any errors?

Comment: No error. Just nothing happens. The why is trying to implement a single entry point to all interaction requests.

Comment: If you are using WPF, and you don't want to use XAML, what part of this presents a UI (the user interaction)? What are you using there? I assume you have to bring something like that into play.

Comment: The PopupNotificationAction takes in a WindowContent = info.View; which is a user control.  Inside the class the GetWindow() builds a new window and places the UserControl inside it and returns it.  But that's never even getting called.   I created an InteractionRequest and bound it to xaml sourceobject as you normally do and saw that the Raised event was not null, while my "ir" variable above does not have it's Raised set and digging into code, if Raised isn't set, then Raise prematurely exits without doing anything which is why I think that's the problem, but don't know how to get that set.

Comment: Have a look here (https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/2dff678713c4f021ab12d0f0816fd09385615d09/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf.Tests/Interactivity/InteractionRequestTriggerFixture.cs). If they can get this to work in a unit test, you could get it to work the way you want. You may just need to approach it differently.

Comment: My guess is that the `InteractionRequestTrigger` is designed not to do anything unless it is attached to some object (since it's an attached trigger). What I'd try in the first place would be to attach it to some object (possibly `irt.Attach(this)`). Note though that it would be better if you've done that once and not every time the interaction is requested - that's at least the outcome when you do it in _XAML_.

Comment: That's what I was missing, was the Attach, thank you.  In the callback I do detach to avoid possible leaks

Comment: I would personally never recommend doing this, but instead use a simple dialog service.  Glad you got it working though.

Comment: The reason I wanted to do this was because I had something going on that would show a dialog, then once that closed automatically open the next one in sequence. In the mean time, errors could navigate you to a new page, based on where the error occurred. When the user closed my IR dialog, the next one wouldn't open because the new dialog brought on by the error didn't have the interaction trigger to know how to do it and that view model may or may not have the info to open it.  We wanted to try to make our IR system more generic and available everywhere to avoid this happening again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, officially to get this to work I made these changes:

```
private void OnInteractionRequestEvent(InteractionRequestEventInfo info)
{
        var ir = new InteractionRequest<INotification>();
        InteractionRequestTrigger irt = new InteractionRequestTrigger();
        PopupNotificationAction pna = new PopupNotificationAction();
        pna.ElementToParent = info.Parent;
        pna.CenterOverAssociatedObject = true;
        pna.IsModal = true;
        pna.WindowContent = info.View;
        irt.Actions.Add(pna);
        irt.Attach(parent);   // added
        irt.SourceObject = ir;
        ir.Raise(info.Notification, () =>
        {
            try
            {
                info.Callback()
            }
            catch
            {
                // exception handling
            }
            finally
            {
                 irt.Detach();   // added
            }
        );
}
```